# ¿Como colocar los codigos de mi base de datos en una tabla de TKinter?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

estoy siguiendo un tutorial de programa de escritorio con TKinter en python y Db Browser para SQLite y no se como puedo insertar el codigo de los productos de mi base de datos en la primera columna de la tabla de la interfaz en TKinter. Este es ell codigo:

#Mostrar datos

```
      for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[2])
```

Con esto solo se muestran los otros datos de la base de datos (productos y cantidad)
[image: Esta es mi base de datos]

Y aparece el nombre del producto en otra columna en mi tabla de TKinter, de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: row probablemente es una tupla. Y Python comienza a contar desde 0. Así que el código del producto es row[0], el nombre row[1] y así sucesivamente. Además cambia ese 0 que está de segundo argumento del insert por "end", el 0 significa que la fila será añadida arriba de todo, lo que terminará haciendo que el orden sea inverso. En cambio, "end" indica "ponlo al final de todo".

Comment: @DanteS. muchas gracias, lo intente pero no logro resolverlo. Lo de la tupla con row[0] funciona, pero solo puedo insertar 2 columnas con los argumentos del insert "text" y "values". Cualquier otro argumento no es valido y me tira un error de sintaxis. ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: Te cuento, los treeviews tienen una columna default, a la que accedes con el parametro text, y a las columnas que siguen son afectadas por el parametro values, al cual debes pasarle un iterable (como una lista o tupla, lo entenderás en el futuro). La verdad, a mi no me gusta recurrir a esa columna default. Puedes hacer invisible la columna default pasando el argumento "show='headings'" durante la creación del treeview. De hecho, si haces lo ultimo, el código que inserta la fila sería `tree.insert("", "end", values=row)`. Espero hayas aprendido algo, lo dije lo mas simple que pude.

Comment: @DanteS. muchas gracias. Me ha sido de gran ayuda tu conocimiento. Al final si he podido resolverlo, poniendo el row[1] y row[2] dentro de "values". Saludos

Comment: De nada! Eso puede funcionar bien, pero hay algo aun mejor que hacer row[1], row[2], ... Te recomiendo investigar sobre los slices o rebanadas, son realmente utiles c: